# What does `import _preamble` do in Python?

Tags: python, import, twisted, twistd

I notice the following at the top of Twisted's `twistd.py` script:

```
import os, sys

try:
    import _preamble
except ImportError:
    sys.exc_clear()

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
```

What does `import _preamble` do? I can't seem to find any references to it on the google-mage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_preamble` is a module like any other. In twisted's case, this is simply [the module](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/bin/_preamble.py) that sets up [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) so that you can run twisted in development setups.

Comment: ah silly me, I didn't consider it might be a module placed in the `bin` directory.